# Duplicate keys from the first entry, wrapping the rest of the keys into values

Tags: json, associative-array, jolt

I'm newbie in jolt and I trying to transform the following JSON

Headers can be different in different json.

I really need a spec based on special characters like *,@,&,$

I'll be eternally grateful for your help!

**Input JSON** :

```json
[
  {
    "header1": null,
    "header2": null,
    "header3": null
  },
  {
    "value1": null,
    "value2": null,
    "value3": null
  },
  {
    "value4": null,
    "value5": null,
    "value6": null
  }
]
```

**Expected Output** :

```json
[
  {
    "header1": "value1",
    "header2": "value2",
    "header3": "value3"
  },
  {
    "header1": "value4",
    "header2": "value5",
    "header3": "value6"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {// separate the first object which has the headers
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "0": {
        "*": {
          "$": "h"
        }
      },
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "v&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// match "headers" against "values" while reforming new nodes to hold each key-value pair group within different objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "v*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@1": "&3.&2.@(4,h[&2])"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// get rid of object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "[#3].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with **2 shift operations** like the below:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "0": {
        "*": {
          "$": "header"
        }
      },
      "*": "data"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "[&2].@(4,header[#2])"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```